# Unable to properly install SonataBluePrintBundle

Tags: git, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, blueprint-css

I couldn't install SonataBluePrintBundle, I used:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/sonata-project/BluePrintBundle.git
```

(with different file destination:example: `src/Bundle/BluePrintBundle`) but when i try to delete cache (or do anything else) i get this error:

```
  PHP Fatal Error: src/Bundle/BluePrintBundle/SonataBluePrintBundle not found in Appkernel.php
```

but it's already added here is the AppKernel file:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
//....
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Bundle\BluePrintBundle\SonataBluePrintBundle(),
    );
//...
```

I tried more than one to change directory &/or path in AppKernel, always same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your git url is bad, according to the [SonataBluePrint repository](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBluePrintBundle), the url is https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBluePrintBundle.git

Try:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBluePrintBundle.git
```

Instead of

```
git submodule add https://github.com/sonata-project/BluePrintBundle.git
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of that ( I made a mistake copying the URL, I've already used the one you wrote) successfully downloaded & installed (according to git), installed it more than once (in many directories, trrying to make the AppKernel recognise its path) but I am getting that error.
(Tried manual install also, no success, maybe I made a mistake installing it manually, I don't know)

Comment: and shouldn't it be `new Sonata\BluePrintBundle\SonataBluePrintBundle(),`?

Comment: Didn't work, I tried every possible combinations (well, I think), I've even installed it in the "src" directory & copied the path, no success.
(I'm thinking to delete all these subbundles installed & try again from the beginning, anyway to do that? I've found a question here asking for that too but I think the method didn't work well in my case)